# Install : libcocos2dcpp.so => libs/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

when I run build_native.sh I allways receive that error:

[armeabi] Install : libcocos2dcpp.so => libs/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so

what should I do to fix that?

The file was missing in its location and I downloaded it, but still have no result.

Comment: What does the complete error message say?

Comment: did your problem solved?

Comment: I think so. I can't remember if it fixed or not cause I posted it 3 month ago and did other stuff.